# Google maps marking path between 2 points over streets

Tags: maps, routes

Maybe it's not the first similar question but anyway:
I'm looking for a kind of functionality to 
make available to mark the vehicle path across the
city streets between two points in city (for example A and B),
including the turns and etc.
Is there some facilities?
If not please offer some idea how it can be done.
Will be appresiated for any help :)
Hope I was clear.

Comment: What's wrong with Google Maps?

Comment: Are you trying to use this in a website? What sort of languages and/or frameworks?

Comment: It's kind of a decision support system for vehicle routing problem using ant algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually construct the URLs based on the parameters that Google Maps has. You can see all the `Direction` parameters (and others) [here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters#Directions).

A basic URL with a source and destination address would look like this:

`http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&geocode=&saddr=ENTERSOURCEADDRESS&daddr=ENTERDESTINATIONADDRESS`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but what can I do if the road locations of my city are not stored at Google because on link you showed here does not mark the way :(

Comment: I get only the markers over the locations I indicated but not the route (

Comment: That's not something you can change. If Google maps doesn't provide you with the route, the API won't provide a route.

Comment: You could try Bing Maps or Ovi maps.

Comment: keyboardP any ideas to make it myself?

Comment: It would be quite tricky to make up the routes yourself if the websites don't provide you with it. If you can find driving directions in Bing or Ovi maps, then you can use their services instead of Google maps.